# Is correct this way to prove that $\dim(V)<\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let be $F$ a field, $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$. Prove that
> if it exist a linear tranformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ with
> $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T))$ both finite, then $\dim(V)$ is finite.

**My attempt:**

Since we know that $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T))<\infty$, there exist a finite basis $B_0 \subset V$ of $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$
Also, there exists $B$ a basis of $V$.

On  another side, let be $x \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$, then $x=T(y)$ for some $y \in V$. We have to note that $y$ is not a linear combination of elements from $B_{0}$, since $T(B_{0})=0$.

Then, $y$ is a linear combination of elements of $B \setminus B_{0}$.

\begin{align}
&\Rightarrow x \text{ is a linear combination of elements from } T(B \setminus B_{0}) \text{ for every } x \in Im(T) \\
&\Rightarrow T(B \setminus B_{0}) \text{ is a basis of } Im(T)\\
&\Rightarrow  T(B \setminus B_{0}) \text{ is finite }\\
&\Rightarrow B \setminus B_{0} \text{ is finite } \\
&\Rightarrow  B \text{ is finite}\\
&\Rightarrow  \dim(V)<\infty
\end{align}

Is my proof correct? In case that it is not, please help me to write it fine. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not enough to choose any basis $B$ of $V$; one has to choose a basis that has something to do with $B_0$. As written, it's quite possible that $B\setminus B_0=B$, and that $T(B)$ is not a basis for Im$(T)$ but merely a spanning set. It might be that your proof does succesfully prove finiteness, but it would not prove the natural refinement that $\dim V = \dim($Im$(T))+\dim($Ker$(T))$.

Comment: So, the proof would be correct if I indicate that $B=B_{0} \cup X$, with $X$ the appropiate subset of $V$, to complete $B_0$ to be a basis of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Take a finite basis $B_0$ of $\text{Ker} T$ and a finite basis $Y$ of $\text{Im} T$. Use this  to create a basis $B_0 \cup X$ of $V$.

Comment: Is it enough to call $B=B_{0} \bigcup X$, with $X$ the appropiate subset of $V$ to complete $B_0$ to be a basis of $V$? And the rest of my proof would be correct?

Comment: No because you don't know that $V$ is finite dimensional. Use a finite set $X$ which is related to $Y$, then prove that $B_0\cup X$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: This would be correct $X=T^{-1}(Y)$? By one side we have that the elements of $B_0$ are linearly independent to the elements of $X$. But how can I show that the elements of $B_0 \cup X$ generates $V$?

Comment: For each $y_i \in Y$, pick one $x_i\in V$ such that $T x_i = y_i$. To prove that $B_0\cup X$ generates $V$, take an arbitrary $x\in V$ and use that $T x\in \text{Im} T$.